# How can i merge two object into one based on key and if same key exist but value is different then add a new key in merged object

Tags: angular, typescript

i am getting multiple objects from which i want to merge object based on order(key), like if order is same for two object then merge it, but i also have question field in all object, those object which have same order should have different question keys and values in the merged array.Please help, any help would be highly appreciated.
Attaching stackblitz for refrence:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-multiple-reactive-forms-copy-969xs5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

i am getting is below:
array that i am getting:

```
[{
    "question": "whats name",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user":"employee",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "choice": "Raj"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "Raj2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "question": "whats",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "choice": "qw"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "qw2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Object that i want:

```
[{
    "messageType": "whats name",
    "eligibleUsers": "whats",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user1":"employee",
    "question_user2":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "choice": "Raj"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "Raj"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: What if both objects have the same field, what value should be retained? Oldest or newest (in sequence)? And in what scenario that both `order` will have same value?

Comment: i have same question field in both object i want that field to be renamed and add two keys for that(i.e. messageType,eligibleUsers)

Comment: based on question_user i tried, i have edited question please take a look

Comment: I believe this can be done with `.reduce()` to transform to a new array. I am just concerned that based on your StackBlitz link, I don't see the possibility that the `order` will have the same value. I want to clarify before providing the answer. Otherwise, it is more like how to change the property key.

Comment: i will get different order for each rule i will add either comment ordropdown type from dropdown.

Comment: i updated stackblitz by removing extra consoles, if you click on rule group new field will add, after filling them on click submit, you can check console the output that i am getting

Comment: Moved from duplicate question: Without worrying about the types, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBBZ4N) do what you want?  It's not clear to me from the question whether you are using a known input interface and only want to renumber a set of known keys, or whether it's dynamic.  My approach assumes a bunch of stuff that might not be what you're looking for. If it works for you I can write up an answer explaining.  If not, please [edit] the question to provide more details of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to merge an array of objects differing for `question_user` in a new object having all `question_user` values indexed in the format of `question_user1`, `question_user2`, `question_userN`.

You could loop through all your objects collecting all `question_user`, storing them in an object and then use [`Object.assign(target, source1, soruce2, ..., sourceN)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge the objects.
This function copies all the properties from `source` object into the `target` object, so if 2 keys are equal, the latest `source` value is kept.

Here's an example, assuming `data` is your array of data:

```
const duplicatedKeys = {}
// Saving all question_user in the format of "question_user1", "question_user2", ...
for (let i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    duplicatedKeys[`question_user${i}`] = data[i-1].question_user
}

// copying all properties from an element of data, i.e. the first
// assigning all duplicated properties
const finalObj= Object.assign(data[0], duplicatedKeys)

// deleting "question_user" of data[0] since you don't want it in your final obj
delete finalObj.question_user;
```

Comment: i want question field from all multiple object that i will get, but with different field name , i dont want to preserve last source value ..i want all the values in merged array,based on same order value.

Comment: Is the merged in this stackblitz the result you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-multiple-reactive-forms-copy-a2ynch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts